# Unable to reference a dynamically created table using document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, function

I am trying to reference the table from a function outside createHTMLTableFromTableObject() using document.getElementById(). I have created a button that prints to the console the reference to the position in the table but all I'm getting is an error. I am obviously not referencing the table correctly but everything ive found online says this is how its done. when i do the exact same console statement inside the createHTMLTableFromTableObject(), it is referenced perfectly. What am i doing wrong and is there any way to reference the table correctly?. Note that this is part of a wider bit of code that randomly generates info for the table, i have cut this out and replaced it with "-" in each cell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    p,
input {
    font: 14px Verdana;
}

.code {
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;   
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background: #FFF}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: rgb(228, 228, 228)}


.htmlTable {
    border: solid 2px #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}

.thCell {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    background-color:rgb(136, 136, 136);
    font: 14px Verdana;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.thAlign {
    text-align: center;
}

.tdCell {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    font: 14px Verdana;
    color: black;
}

.tdTxtAlign {
    text-align: left;
}

.tdNumAlign {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Convert JavaScript Object Data to HTML Table</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- View showing Table containing randonly generated data -->
    <!-- And a Button to generate another random table-->
    <div>
        <div style="padding: 20px; text-align: center;"><input type="button" onclick="createHTMLTableFromTableObject()"
                value="Create Table From JavaScript Object" /></div>
        <table style="padding: 20px;" id="showTableData"></table>

        <div style="padding: 20px; text-align: center;"><input type="button" onclick="testRef()"
            value="Test Reference to Table" /></div>

</div>
    <!-- Function to generate a JS Table Object, and a function to convert to HTML Table --> 
    <script>
        //
        // The table object - it is the data model!
        //
        var myTable = []; 

        //
        // generate random data to populate the table model (populates a JavaScript object)
        //
        function genNewTable(table, numRows) {
            for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                // generate table row with random data
                table.push({
                    "Student Name": "-",
                    "Student ID": "-",
                    "Assignment 1": "-",
                    "Assignment 2": "-",
                    "Assignment 3": "-",
                    "Assignment 4": "-",
                    "Assignment 5": "-",
                    "Average (%)": null
                });
                // calculate the average grade for the last generated record inserted into table
                numAssignments = -3; averageGrade = 0;
                studentRecord = table[table.length - 1];
                // get the keys for any column matching "assignment"
                // var assignmentKeys = Object.keys(studentRecord).filter((assignment) => /Assignment/.test(assignment));
                // get total grades (not averaged) just to see what you can do with filter
                // Object.keys(studentRecord).filter((assignment) => averageGrade += (/Assignment/.test(assignment))?studentRecord[assignment]:0);
                for (var column in studentRecord) {
                    if (/^Assignment/.test(column))
                        averageGrade += studentRecord[column]; 
                        numAssignments++;
                }
                averageGrade = Math.round(averageGrade / numAssignments);
                // set the final column to the average grade for the randomly generated grades
                studentRecord["Average (%)"] = averageGrade +"%";
            }
        }
        //
        // generate a table from the JavaScript (JSON) object
        //
        function createHTMLTableFromTableObject() {
            // generate a new table using random data
            myTable = []; genNewTable(myTable, 10);

            // extract the column headers from the current data model (using first row of data model)
            var colHeaders = Object.keys(myTable[0]);

            // create the <table> object for inserting into DOM
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.setAttribute("class", "htmlTable");

            // create the <table> header row first using extracted headers
            var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                  // create the row (at end of table)                
            for (var i = 0; i < colHeaders.length; i++) {
                var th = document.createElement("th");     // and the headers
                th.setAttribute("class", "thCell thAlign");     // add the styles
                th.innerHTML = colHeaders[i];
                tr.appendChild(th);
            }

            // add the data from the table object as rows
            for (var i = 0; i < myTable.length; i++) {
                tr = table.insertRow(-1); // insert row at end of table
                for (var j = 0; j < colHeaders.length; j++) {
                    var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1); // insert at end of row
                    if (j<2) {
                        tabCell.setAttribute("class", "tdCell tdTxtAlign");
                    } else {
                        tabCell.setAttribute("class", "tdCell tdNumAlign");
                        tabCell.contentEditable = true;
                    }
                    tabCell.innerHTML = myTable[i][colHeaders[j]];
                    //console.log(table.rows[i+1].cells[j]);        <---------- PERFECT REFERENCE
                }
            }
            // now update the table view (container)
            var viewContainer = document.getElementById("showTableData");
            viewContainer.innerHTML = ""; // reset
            viewContainer.appendChild(table); // add the table
        }
        
        function testRef()
        {
            var table = document.getElementById("showTableData");
            console.log(table.rows[0].cells[1]);
        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: tabletest.html:161 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined
    at testRef (tabletest.html:161)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (tabletest.html:70)

Comment: note i do not get this error when the console.log statement is executed inside the function that assembles the table

Comment: are you hitting the testRef button first? Because then of course there is not table in the dom.

Comment: no, i am generating it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are placing that generated table into the already existing table (with id: showTableData) and then you are calling that table.

it would return something like `<table id="showTableData"><table class="htmlTable"></table></table>`

and you want to address the second one or better yet don't place a table inside the other table :)

```
function testRef()
{
    var table = document.querySelector(".htmlTable");
    console.log(table.rows[0].cells[1]);
}
```

this is a quick fix (proof) but you should spawn that generated table into the container directly.

Edit 1: answering further question

in javascript change

```
table.setAttribute("class", "htmlTable");
```

to

```
table.setAttribute("id", "showTableData");
```

you can also keep both if you need that class name.

Next this line that currently addresses the first table

```
var viewContainer = document.getElementById("showTableData");
```

change to

```
var viewContainer = document.getElementById("showTableData_container");
```

and lastly in HTML

```
<table style="padding: 20px;" id="showTableData"></table>
```

to this

```
<div style="padding: 20px;" id="showTableData_container"></div>
```

you can now use the original test function

```
function testRef()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("showTableData");
    console.log(table.rows[0].cells[1]);
}
```

Comment: ok i see thank you, that works but how would you spawn it into the container directly?

Comment: no problem I've made an edit with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In your code yo wrote:

```
        // create the <table> object for inserting into DOM
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute("class", "htmlTable");
```

And this table is not the same to the one with id="showTableData"

To get the content of the first row of the table that you create with the function createHTMLTableFromTableObject:

```
    function testRef(){
        var table = document.querySelector(".htmlTable");
        console.log(table.rows[0].cells[1]);
    }
```